# Imagem quebra o título

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma imagem e embaixo dela tenho um título, ao lado tenho três bloco. 
Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu adiciono apenas uma linha de título, ele quebra, a imagem acaba descendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria deixar a imagem todas iguais com uma linha ou com duas linhas, elas não se movesse, como na primeira imagem?

**HTML**

```
<section class="lectures">
    <article class="lectures-content">
        <img src="http://imagens.canaltech.com.br/54960.81428-Facebook.jpg">
            <h3 class="lectures-title"><a href="#">Performance em CSS - BrazilJS 2012 DUAS LINHAS</a></h3>
            <span class="lectures-about">Link da palestra:</span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Duração:<strong>10:20</strong></span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Palestrante:<strong>Paul Ishid</strong></span>
             <span class="watch"><a href="#">Assista agora</a></span> 
    </article>
</section>
<section class="lectures">
    <article class="lectures-content">
        <img src="http://imagens.canaltech.com.br/54960.81428-Facebook.jpg">
            <h3 class="lectures-title"><a href="#">Performance em CSS - BrazilJS 2012</a></h3>
            <span class="lectures-about">Link da palestra:</span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Duração:<strong>10:20</strong></span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Palestrante:<strong>Paul Ishid</strong></span>
             <span class="watch"><a href="#">Assista agora</a></span> 
    </article>
</section>
<section class="lectures">
    <article class="lectures-content">
        <img src="http://imagens.canaltech.com.br/54960.81428-Facebook.jpg">
            <h3 class="lectures-title"><a href="#">Performance em CSS - BrazilJS 2012 DUAS LINHAS</a></h3>
            <span class="lectures-about">Link da palestra:</span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Duração:<strong>10:20</strong></span>
            <span class="lectures-about">Palestrante:<strong>Paul Ishid</strong></span>
             <span class="watch"><a href="#">Assista agora</a></span> 
    </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.lectures {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-family: 'Aleo';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
  .lectures:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px; }
  .lectures img {
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  .lectures .lectures-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin: 5px; }
    .lectures .lectures-title a {
      color: #D90452; }
  .lectures .lectures-about {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f2d750;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #8e7300; }
  .lectures strong {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #F2F2F2; }
  .lectures h3 {
    height: 50px;
  }

.watch {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
  .watch a {
    background: #f2d750;
    color: #D90452;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #8e7300;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto; }
```

http://codepen.io/Andersonn/pen/KCxyr

Answer (score 3):

**1) Solução**

Foi adicionado:

```
.lectures h3 {
    height: 50px;
  }
```

No código Css completo:

```
.lectures {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-family: 'Aleo';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
  .lectures:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px; }
  .lectures img {
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  .lectures .lectures-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin: 5px; }
    .lectures .lectures-title a {
      color: #D90452; }
  .lectures .lectures-about {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f2d750;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #8e7300; }
  .lectures strong {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #F2F2F2; }
  .lectures h3 {
    height: 50px;
  }

.watch {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
  .watch a {
    background: #f2d750;
    color: #D90452;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #8e7300;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto; }
```

---

**2) Solução:**

Foi adicionado `height: 50px` em `.lectures .lectures-title`

```
.lectures .lectures-title {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        margin: 5px; height: 50px;}
```

No Código Css Completo

```
.lectures {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-family: 'Aleo';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
  .lectures:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px; }
  .lectures img {
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px; }
  .lectures .lectures-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin: 5px; height: 50px;}
    .lectures .lectures-title a {
      color: #D90452; }
  .lectures .lectures-about {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f2d750;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #8e7300; }
  .lectures strong {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #F2F2F2; }  

.watch {
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
  .watch a {
    background: #f2d750;
    color: #D90452;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #8e7300;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto; }
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBlef)

Comment: Muito bom! Estava martelando aqui a cabeça pra tentar achar, Obrigado @Maria

Comment: Outra possibilidade é mexer no `vertical-align`.

Comment: @bfavaretto esse foi meu primeiro comentário sem ver nada, mas, o que acontece ele tem mais itens abaixo igual está no CodePen dá uma olhada: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBlef

Comment: Ah, agora entendi.